# Hiding an anchor and span with css in IE7

Tags: css

For simplicity I've created my style in the document to highlight my problem.  I have a row of 4  links that are styled to look like button.  The Next link (the 3rd item) I am hiding using css.  In IE8+, Chrome, Firefox it works perfectly but in IE7, there is a gap between the Cancel and Accept button (where the Next button would be).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ButtonBar
            {
                margin-top: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .LinkButton
            {
                background-color: #01699b;
                border: 0px solid;
                border-radius: 14px;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 28px;
                padding: 0px 11px 0px 11px;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                line-height: 28px;
            }
            .NextButton
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ButtonBar">
            <a class="PreviousButton"><span class="LinkButton">Previous</span></a>
            <a class="CancelButton"><span class="LinkButton">Cancel</span></a>
            <a class="NextButton"><span class="LinkButton">Next</span></a>
            <a class="AcceptButton"><span class="LinkButton">Accept</span></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you remove all CSS from the .LinkButton class apart from background-color it does the same, I was just including it all to show what I am doing so far.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: what happens if you float the links left?

Comment: Float left does work, I think have to add a margin-right on them to space them out.  But how would I center align the button within the "button bar"?

Comment: ah you can't use float left then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you ever wonder where these spaces actually come from?

It's the linebreaks between your inline-elements `<a>` causing a gap.

```
    <div class="ButtonBar">
        <a class="PreviousButton">...</a> <!-- Linebreak! -->
        <a class="CancelButton">...</a>   <!-- Linebreak! -->
        <a class="NextButton">...</a>     <!-- Linebreak! -->
        <a class="AcceptButton">...</a>   <!-- Linebreak! -->
    </div>
```

Now the modern browsers collapse multiple of these, but IE7 does not, so you have actually 2 linebreaks between your elements, causing the gap to be double as wide.

You have several solutions to this:

1) Floating the elements

2) modifying markup:

```
     <!-- end tag on the new line -->
     <a>...
     </a><a>...
     </a>...

     <!-- comments in between -->
     <a>...</a><!--
  --><a>...</a>

     <!-- all on one line -->
     <a>...</a><a>...</a>

     <!-- In some cases (e.g. list elements) you can skip the end tag -->
```

3) Modifying font sizes

4) Using negative margins- but that could cause issues in older browsers.

What solution you want to take is up to you.

**For your special case, where you just hide the element in question you could either declare absolute `position` or any `float` on that element.**

Comment: Perfect, the all one one line approach seemed the easy solution.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add float:left ONLY to the .NextButton css class. This should work.

Comment: +1 Won't work for the general problem, but in this special case it's working;)